# Can you use absolute paths in Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, npm, gulp, electron

Simple question here that I can't seem to find a straight answer for.

Is there any way to use absolute paths for dependencies (e.g. `<script src="/my-script.js"></script>`) with electron and have it work?

Currently it just does `mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');`

Which loads index.html just fine, but here's the thing, index.html loads

Which fails because it looks in the root of the entire hard drive

This would make my life quite a bit easier, as otherwise i'd have to refactor a bunch of template URLs, and doing some would forever break my app if I ever wanted to add pages in a subdirectory on the website (e.g. http://website.com/m/).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can override built-in URI to file-path resolution using [`protocol.interceptFileProcotol()`](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md#protocolinterceptfileprotocolscheme-handler-completion), your handler can then map `/my-script.js` to whatever path you want.

Comment: We use `protocol.registerFileProtocol('app', ...` with `protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['app'])` to make `window.history.pushState` work and `webFrame.registerURLSchemeAsSecure('app')` to make `getUserMedia` work.

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths work just fine.. Try removing the first `/` like so: `<script src="my-script.js"></script>`

If you really need access the your apps absolute path you can get it with `app.getAppPath()`:

```
var app = require('remote').require('app');
console.log(app.getAppPath());
```

And you could load scripts by injecting them into the DOM with a small amount of inline JS.

Comment: They don't work if I'm using pushState and thus my templates could be loaded from any url.